How can I align items while maintaining the alignment of the rightmost column by wrapping them in a div?
I'm utilizing Vue.js, a UI component framework for Vue.js. Currently, I'm encountering an issue where I can't align numbers like 500 or 5000, as well as aligning icons. The numbers in the rightmost column must be preserved, so I wrapped them in a div. How can I fix it?
<v-list-item
  v-for="result in results"
  :key="result.id"
  class="grey lighten-3 mb-1"
>
  <v-list-item-content class="my-1 px-2">
    <v-list-item-title>
      {{ $datetime(new Date(result.timestamp * 1000)) }}
    </v-list-item-title>
  </v-list-item-content>
  <div>
    <v-list-item-content
      v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndUp"
      class="my-1 px-2"
    >
      <v-list-item-title>
        {{ $n(result.used) }}
        <v-icon size="20">
          mdi-arrow-right-bold
        </v-icon>
      </v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </div>
  <div>
    <v-list-item-content class="my-1 px-2">
      <v-list-item-title>
        {{ $n(result.point) }}
      </v-list-item-title>
    </v-list-item-content>
  </div>
</v-list-item>


It looks like a table to me, why not just use <table>?

Yes, i was trying to use v-data-table for vuetify, but when breakpoint to xs, the UI format doesn't meet our requirement.

Here's an approach that uses subgrid to align items across deep nested elements. See if it helps.


.entries {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(3, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  gap: 10px;
}

.entry {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}

.before {
  justify-self: end;
}

/* if you need to align right most numbers to the right, uncomment this
.after {
  justify-self: end;
}
*/
<div class="entries">
  <div class="entry">
    <time>2024-04-17 12:12:23</time>
    <div class="before">500</div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="after">5,000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <time>2024-04-17 12:13:23</time>
    <div class="before">500</div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="after">5,000,000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <time>2024-04-17 12:14:23</time>
    <div class="before">500,000,000</div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="after">500</div>
  </div>
  <div class="entry">
    <time>2024-04-17 12:15:23</time>
    <div class="before">500,000</div>
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="after">1,500,000,000</div>
  </div>
</div>



